# MongoDb speed decrease

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I use mongodb to store compressed html files .
Basically, a complete document of mongod is like:

```
{'_id': 1, 'p1': data, 'p2': data2, 'p3': data3}
```

where data, data1, data3 are :`bson.binary.Binary(zlib_compressed_html)`

I have 12 Million ids and dataX are each one average 90KB, 
so each document has at least size `180KB + sizeof(_id) + some_overhead`.

The total data size would be at least 2TB.

I would like to notice that `'_id'` is index.

I insert to mongo with the following way:

```
def _save(self, mongo_col, my_id, page, html):
    doc = mongo_col.find_one({'_id': my_id})
    key = 'p%d' % page
    success = False
    if doc is None:
        doc = {'_id': my_id, key: html}
        try:
            mongo_col.save(doc, safe=True)
            success = True
        except:
            log.exception('Exception saving to mongodb')
    else:
        try:
            mongo_col.update({'_id': my_id}, {'$set': {key: html}})
            success = True
        except:
            log.exception('Exception updating  mongodb')
    return success
```

As you can see first I lookup the collection to see if a document with 
my_id exists.

If it does not exist then I create it and save it to mongo else I update it.

The problem with the above is that although it was super fast, at some point it became really slow.

I will give you some numbers:

When it was fast I was doing 1.500.000 per 4 hours and after 300.000 per 4 hours.

I suspect that this affects the speed:

Note

When performing update operations that increase the document size beyond the allocated space for that document, the update operation relocates the document on disk and may reorder the document fields depending on the type of update.

`As of these driver versions, all write operations will issue a getLastError command to confirm the result of the write operation:
{ getLastError: 1 }
Refer to the documentation on write concern in the Write Operations document for more information.`

the above is from : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/

I am saying that because we could have the following :

`{'_id: 1, 'p1': some_data}, ...., {'_id': 10000000, 'p2': some_data2}, ...{'_id': N, 'p1': sd3}`

and imagine that I am calling the above _save method as:

`_save(my_collection, 1, 2, bin_compressed_html)`

Then it should update the doc with _id 1 . But if the thing that mongo site is the case,
because I am adding a key to the document it does not fit and should rearrange the document.

It is possible to move the document in the end of the collection, which could be very far on the disk. Could this slow things down?

Or speed slow down has to do with the size of the collection?

In any way to you think it should be more efficient to modify my structure to be like:

`{'_id': ObjectId, 'mid': 1, 'p': 1, 'd': html}`

where mid=my_id, p=page, d=compressed html

and modify _save method to do only inserts?

```
def _save(self, mongo_col, my_id, page, html):
    doc = {'mid': my_id, 'p': page, 'd': html}
    success = False
    try:
        mongo_col.save(doc, safe=True)
        success = True
    except:
        log.exception('Exception saving to mongodb')
    return success
```

this way I avoid the update (so the rearrange on disk) and one lookup (find_one) 
but the documents would be 3x mores and I would have 2 indexes ( _id and mid ) .

What do you suggest?

Comment: safe argument for the save method is deprecated; just except clause - bad practice; insert + update = upsert (one operation). You should really try your second approach and compare them.

Comment: w=1 is equivalent with safe?; I do not care which exception happened as long as it did not write to mongo; Yes I should try but what should happen in theory?

Comment: yes it is. if an updating does not change the size of the document a lot, document will not be relocated. try usepowerOf2Sizes if you use 2.2.1+ version.

Comment: as i understood powerOf2Sizes will work as following in my case:
in my first insert (one page = 90K) it will allocate 128K. So in the second insert it will reallocate the document and will assign :
(128+90 = 218 ) 256K of disk. At the third insert there are available only 38K so it will reallocate again. It's no guaranteed that it will help. (it depends of the document size)

Comment: in your last example you are doing just inserts, you don't change any document. so, no speed changes, i suppose.

Comment: yeah, I am talking about the updates. I will try and I will update. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Document relocation could be an issue if you continue to add pages of html as new attributes. Would it really be an issue to move pages to a new collection where you could simply add them one record each? Also I don't really think MongoDB is a good fit for your use case. E.g. [Redis](http://redis.io/) would be much more efficient. 
Another thing you should take care of is to [have enough ram](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage) for your _id index. Use db.mongocol.stats() to check the index size.

Comment: So do you think that if the first time I create a document I add all atributes I would not have the rellocation problem?

Answer (score 0):

When inserting new Documents into MongoDB, a Document can grow without moving it up to a certain point. Because the DB is analyzing the incoming Data and adds a padding to the Document.
So do deal with less Document movements you can do two things:

1. manually tweaking the padding factor
2. preallocate space (attributes) for each document.

See [Article about Padding](http://tebros.com/2010/11/mongodb-paddingfactor-implications/) or [MongoDB Docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor) for more Information about the padding factor.

Btw. insetad of using save for creating new documents, you should use .insert() which will throw a duplicate key error if the _id is already there (.save() will overwrite your document)